# Trasparent background not suppoerted in material theme

Tags: android, material-design

> I designed app using material theme but its not supporting transparent background as I updated the dependencies I dont know why it happened . Is there any way to use transparent background . The material theme is using my primary color every where i used the transparent background

**COLOR.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="Colorprimary">#ffcc80</color>
<color name="primaryLightColor">#ffffb0</color>
<color name="primaryDarkColor">#ca9b52</color>
<color name="primaryTextColor">#000000</color>
<color name="trns">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Colorprimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
    <item name="background">@color/trns</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/share"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/trns"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/star"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rate"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/trns"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/info"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/trns"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

please look at the image now
[image]

previously my app ui looks clean 
please look
[image]

Comment: Can you try backgroundTint instead of background?

Comment: i used it but not effect

Comment: Have you tried toolbar background transparency. It seems toolbar background.